# How to show json result (which is partial view) as a modal pop up?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, json

I am trying to show a modal pop up by making a getjson call like this from my javascript:

```
 $.getJSON('/Home/somefunction', function(result) {
       var toto = $(result);
       alert(toto);
       });

      public ActionResult somefunction()
      {
         return new JsonResult { Data = PartialView("modal pop up partial view") };
      }
```

My modal pop up view is partialview.

1. I don't know if this is right way to convert partial view into jsonresult inside my controller function.
2. I dont know, how to use the result in getjson to show was pop up(do I need to assign to any div)?

Thanks

Comment: You want to make a partial view into a JSON result? I'm confused about why you'd want to do this. What do you actually want to show in the modal popup?

Comment: I wanted to show my partial view as modal pop, I think it was clearly mentioned in the subject.

Comment: Well not really, because you said you wanted a JSON result as a modal popup. It seems that what you actually want to do is display HTML markup inside a modal popup using an AJAX request to load it. Nothing to do with JSON at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The better way is to return a PartialView from the controller.  Use `$.get` or `$.ajax` to make a GET request to the server (or a POST if you need), and the callback will have the HTML.  You can then inject the HTML into the parent view (inside the modal).

Comment: Yes, partial views are the key. Another option is $.load http://api.jquery.com/load/

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take a look at [FancyBox](http://fancybox.net/) library, very easy to use for your situation.